# OleDbConnection Source Variable in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, c#-2.0

How can I replace `D:\temp\test.xls` with `filePath` in `OleDbConnection` statement.

I can get the exactly filePath (with OpenFileDialog, then I can located my .xls file conveniently, no more hardcoded), but when I insert the variable `filePath` as Style2, it doesn't work. How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Style1

```
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""");
```

Style2

```
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=filePath;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""");
```

[Updated]
Some part of my code as this,

```
DataTable fooData = new DataTable();

            OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=filePath;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""");

            dbConnection.Open ();
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [maleSheet$]", dbConnection);
                OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                int RankIndex = dbReader.GetOrdinal("Rank");

                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    string rank = dbReader.GetValue(RankIndex).ToString();
                    ////....
                }
           }
```

Error as below at line `OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();`

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: whats the exact error and where you are getting at the Connection String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection( String.Format( @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""", filePath ) );
```

Comment: NP. You have to remember the C# doesn't do automatic variable substitution, unlike, say, PHP.